# Combinations of multiple vectors in R

Tags: r, combinations

I'm not sure if permutations is the correct word for this. I want to given a set of n vectors (i.e. `[1,2]`,`[3,4]` and `[2,3]`) permute them all and get an output of

```
[1,3,2],[1,3,3],[1,4,2],[1,4,3],[2,3,2] etc.
```

Is there an operation in R that will do this?

Comment: I believe you are describing combinations. Permutations are similar to combinations, but the order of elements matter.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is a useful case for storing the vectors in a list and using `do.call()` to arrange for an appropriate function call for you. `expand.grid()` is the standard function you want. But so you don't have to type out or name individual vectors, try:

```
> l <- list(a = 1:2, b = 3:4, c = 2:3)
> do.call(expand.grid, l)
  a b c
1 1 3 2
2 2 3 2
3 1 4 2
4 2 4 2
5 1 3 3
6 2 3 3
7 1 4 3
8 2 4 3
```

However, for all my cleverness, it turns out that `expand.grid()` accepts a list:

```
> expand.grid(l)
  a b c
1 1 3 2
2 2 3 2
3 1 4 2
4 2 4 2
5 1 3 3
6 2 3 3
7 1 4 3
8 2 4 3
```

Comment: @Andrie How embarrassing! Trying to be *too* clever does have its advantages it would appear. I don't deserve the Accept here though. I shall make amends with some upvotes.

Answer (score 14):

This is what `expand.grid` does.

Quoting from the help page: *Create a data frame from all combinations of the supplied vectors or factors*.  The result is a `data.frame` with a row for each combination.

```
expand.grid(
    c(1, 2),
    c(3, 4),
    c(2, 3)
)

  Var1 Var2 Var3
1    1    3    2
2    2    3    2
3    1    4    2
4    2    4    2
5    1    3    3
6    2    3    3
7    1    4    3
8    2    4    3
```

Comment: Hi, I am trying this approach, but am getting the message: "Error in rep.int(rep.int(seq_len(nx), rep.int(rep.fac, nx)), orep) : 
  vector is too large" Are there any alternative ways to do this?

Comment: @user1375871 How large are your vectors?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `expand.grid()` you could use `rep()` to produce the desired combination. Consider the following simplified example using the original data from this question:

```
a <- c(1,2)
b <- c(3,4)
c <- c(2,3)
```

To get the `expand.grid()`-like effect, use `rep()` with a `times=` argument equal to the product of the length of the other vectors (or 4). The middle vector would use a nested `rep()` with products of vector length to either side (or 2 and 2). The end vector is like the first but with `each=` argument in order to pattern correctly. This is trivial to calculate when each vector is length of 2. Example:

```
#tibble of all combinations of a, b and c
tibble::tibble(
var1 = rep(a, times = 4),
var2 = rep(rep(b, each= 2), times = 2), #nested rep()
var3 = rep(c, each= 4)
)
```

For an unknown number of input vectors (or unknown vector lengths), we can get all combinations with `rep()` in a function like this:

```
#Produces a tibble of all combinations of input vectors
expand_tibble <- function(...){ 
  x <- list(...) #all input vectors stored here
  l <- lapply(x,length)|> unlist() #vector showing length of each input vector
  t <- length(l) #total input vector count
  r <-list() #empty list
  for(i in 1:t){
    if(i==1){ #first input vector
      first <-l[2:length(l)] |> prod()
       r[[i]]<-rep(x[[i]], each = first)
    }else{   #last input vector
    if(i==t){
    last  <- l[1:t-1] |> prod()
    r[[i]]<-rep(x[[i]], last)
    }else{   #all middle input vectors
      m1 <- l[1:(i-1)] |> prod()
      m2 <- l[(i+1):t] |> prod()  
    r[[i]] <- rep(rep(x[[i]], each=m1),m2)
        }
    }
    names(r)[i]<-paste0("var",i)
    }
  tibble::as_tibble(r)
}
```

output:

```
expand_tibble(a,b,c)
 var1  var2  var3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     3     2
2     1     3     3
3     1     4     2
4     1     4     3
5     2     3     2
6     2     3     3
7     2     4     2
8     2     4     3
```