# How to get permutations by selecting one member of a subset with multiple subsets in R?

Tags: r, matrix, set, combinations, permutation

Ok so in R, I want to determine the list of permutations without replacement of a list of variables, but for some of those variables I want to use only one item from each subset. So for example:

```
Set1: [a1, a2, a3]
Set2: [b1, b2, b3]
Set3: [c1, c2, c3]
Set4: [d1, d2, d3]
...
```

And so I want to pick only one of the variables from each set (Set1 - Set 4+) and combine them with only one of the variables from the other sets. Giving results like:

```
results =

        Val1 Val2 Val3 Val4
perm1:  a1   b3   c2   d1
perm2:  a3   b1   c3   d2
perm3:  a2   b2   c1   d3
```

So its a permutation where each slot (Val1, Val2 etc) has a subgroup of possibilities to pick from (Set1, Set2 etc). Does that make sense?

I'm aware of several packages for normal permutations  and combinations (packages gtools, combinat, permutations, etc) but I am having trouble finding a package or function that would handle this sort of subgroup structure. Its important to note that I would not want multiple variable picks from the same set, just one pick per set (so just a1 or a3, not both, for each permutation).

Comment: Check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108098/combinations-of-multiple-vectors-in-r Best!

Comment: Thanks @JonnyCrunch